# AutoFill - Como selecionar a segunda linha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Caros, tenho o seguinte problema:

Estou preenchendo uma celula com uma formula e preciso que seja duplicada para as demais. Então estou o usando o código

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C329")
```

Problema:

Sempre quando executo essa função, eu faço um filtro na coluna para exibir somente os #N/D. E em seguida executar o código novamente (com outros parametros).

Mas ele sempre vai executar o código nesse range C2:C329, e pode ser que dentro desse range eu não tenha os #N/D.

O que preciso:

Preciso selecionar sempre a segunda linha da planilha, pois a primeira é estática.

tentei com o código

```
    Range("a1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Activate
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Podem me ajudar.

Comment: Sugiro usar as tabelas do Excel para facilitar sua vida neste caso e trabalhar com elas. Poderia filtrar tudo o que tem `#N/D` e rodar seu código facilmente usando o seguinte módulo: https://github.com/evertramos/excel-modules/blob/master/m_TableFuncions.bas que possui diversas funções para trabalhar com as Tabelas do Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

> Pego a minha coluna que contem mais dados, nesse caso é a coluna "A", nunca vai existir uma célula em branco.

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, "B" & lastRow)

> Depois realizo o AutoFill da minha célula atual (selecionada), até a coluna onde irei jogar a formulá, dentro do range B & lastRow
>   lastRow, esta sendo a quantidade de linhas, da ultima celulá de "A" que contem dados, até a A1.

Answer (score 3):

Não tenho bem certeza que compreendi sua questão, mas se vc quer deixar a o range variável, de acordo com o o resultado do seu filtro, vc pode substituir:

```
Destination:=Range("C2:C329")
```

por:

```
Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
```

Assim, serão selecionadas, sempre, todas as células abaixo da referência ativa.

> **NOTA:** Estou assumindo que vc não tem nenhuma linha em branco na sua seleção, ja que ela vai estar filtrada.

*edited*

se vc quer substituir as células que tem #N/D em uma coluna vc pode usar a seguinte abordagem:

> Atente que estou usando `On Error Resume Next`o que não é recomendável, mas resolve seu problema por hora. Se conseguir pensar em algo para contornar a incompatibilidade quando o código compara "" com um Erro seria uma boa melhoria.

```
Sub replaceNAs()
  On Error Resume Next 'quando a macro encontrar #N/D o valor não é comparável com "",
  Dim offsetCount As Integer
  Dim ref As Range: Set ref = Range("C2") ' célula de referência
  offsetCount = 0 'valor do offset

  While Not ref.Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = "" 'enquanto o valor da célula não for vazio
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ref.Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value) Then 'caso seja #N/D
      If ref.Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        ref.Offset(offsetCount, 0).FormulaR1C1 = ref.FormulaR1C1 'a célula atual recebe a fórmula da célula de referencia
      End If
    End If
    offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
  Wend 
End Sub
```

Comment: Tentei aqui com sua sugestão, funcionou, mas não com o resultado esperado.

É possível selecionar um limite para essa minha seleção ? Pois esta aplicando para todas as células da coluna.

Ex:Até a C329

Comment: Estou tentando com o seguinte código

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(A2, Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select)

Mas sem sucesso também.

O método 'Range' do objeto '_Global' falhou

Comment: E quando executo essa parte do código, ainda não esta filtrado.

Comment: Vc quer aplicar uma fórmula em todas as células que estão como #N/D, é isso?
Talvez a melhor abordagem seja um laço verificando que se o valor da célula é o erro e, caso positivo, atribui a formula no R1C1.

Comment: editei a resposta, veja se isso te atende.

Comment: Acredito que os #N/D não seja o problema, pois com eles eu fico até onde eu devo ir.

Ex:

Eu basicamente faço um PROCV na planilha de OUTUBRO e se não retornar irá ficar com #N/D, Na próxima macro, irei buscar no mês SETEMBRO. Sempre filtrando somente os #N/D, pois são eles que quero finalizar.

Comment: Nesse caso não seria melhor vc não usar o VBA mas a função SEERRO?
assim vc pode concatenar todas as possibilidades.

Comment: As planilhas dos meses são muito pesadas para eu utilizar dessa forma.
No VBA eu realizo a abertura delas, consulto e depois fecho.